# Symfony2 how to use CDN with liipimagineBundle?

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle

i want to host all my assets (img, css, js, ...) on a CDN, no aws!

How to do that with liipimagineBundle ?

Thank you !

Comment: thank you for downvote, my pleasure !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this not possible without write a custom loader, manager, factory... i used a modified version of: https://github.com/flug/imagine-bundle

Answer (score 1):

Read the following:

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-the-new-asset-component

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset/introduction.html

https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html

And the assetic documentation.

Looking at LiipImagineBundle, it seems they just provide filters/functions that you use in twig, so you would call both normally.

If this response is not enough, or clear, let me know and I'll edit it to fill in what I can.

Thank you.

Comment: i know assetic, but the question is for liipimagineBundle, because path are relative, and i need absolute path with filters as {{ image.absolutepath|imagine_filter('sylius_medium') }}